# Small dead space on a div button in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, onclick, position, css-position

I can't explain this one.  I've got a div that's a button.  I use the :active psuedo class and position: relative; to move it slightly down and to the right when clicked, to give it an animation.  For some reason, there is a small dead space on this button in Chrome about half way between the text and edge of the button.  The psuedo class still fires but the Javascript on the button does not.  If I remove the position relative, the problem goes away.  This also happens in Firefox, but the deadspace in Firefox is on the very edge where the button moves out of the way, which makes sense but also needs to be fixed.

I created a JSFiddle to show the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/dillydadally/CUHA7/6/

Any idea why this is happening?  Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Weird how only with Chrome that the callback isn't called when hitting the 'sweet spot'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS. It's because of **margin: 10px;** on **#btn**

EDIT

If you use **onmousedown** rather **onclick** it will work.

Explaining:

The pseudo class is being activate before the onClick. If you change the values of :active from 2px to 20px. You will see this happening even if you are clicking on the middle of the button.

So after the new values of left and top set by the :active, the mouse isn't on top of the div anymore and can't register the **click** (***press and release***).

But **onmousedown** is still triggered because it doesn't depend on the release of the mouse's button.

Comment: no, because the margin affects outside of the button, not to the div section, so this shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Sorry i got it wrong. I thought you were complaining about the space between the text and the button.

Comment: it's talking about a strange effect. When you click in some area of the div, the CSS:active is executed but the JavaScript call is not being produced.

Comment: Now i'm seeing. Interesting. Never saw this before but i will tell you what is happening. The pseudo class is being activate before the onCLick. So after the new values of left and top. You are not with the mouse on top of the div anymore. 

If you change the values of :active from 2px to 20px. You will see this happening even if you are clicking on the middle of the button.

Comment: The question is not mine, but it could be an answer... but, actually, when the state is at active there's a part where you're still at the div but the javascript is not being executed.

Comment: @Diego That is accurate for Firefox, but you'll notice in Chrome with the 2px value there is a dead space in an area that is still under the button after clicking.  Weird, huh?  I'm betting it's still related to that though.  Any ideas to fix it?  I guess I could do the movement in Javascript on both a mouse down and a mouse up.  What a pain :(

Comment: @dallin i changed my answer and now i'm explaining and giving you a way to make this work. You can change the "onclick" to "onmousedown" on your fiddle to see how it will work

Comment: Awesome! That's the ticket! Worked perfectly!  It's weird that Chrome had a dead space when still under the button though.